# String not wrap

Tags: css

I have **[this code](http://jsfiddle.net/styf5y0e/)** in my plugin and I cannot wrap the text of the `span` element inside the `<div class="srb_display_url></div>` element.

In my console I have try all of the folloing but with no luck

```
word-break: break-all !important;
```

and

```
word-wrap: break-word !important;
```

as well this

```
word-break: break-all !important;
word-wrap: break-word !important;
```

What I am doing wrong ? Can somebody to help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `white-space: nowrap` style for the `.srb_display_url` element.

Comment: Thanks Nitha, I will mark your answer as correct in four minutes due to Stackoverflow limitations :)

Answer (score 0):

Just increase your width and height and should be fine.

```
.parent_container
{
    display : block;
    width : 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background : #EAEAEA;
    padding-top: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunatelly it is not usefull. This code is inside a WordPress plugin, and I need to set the width of my plugin content dynamicly.